# How do l disable this gradient color effect on my UV texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

I apologize for my noobidity, but how can I disable this gradient thing? I need accurate, solid colors. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: l'm assuming this has to do with the interpolation (filtering mode) of the image texture. You can probably find this in an Image Texture node in the Shader node editor. Set "lnterpolation" to Closest.

Comment: Thank you, just what was needed! I was using UV Map node for some reason, so there was no option to change interpolation, but changing it to Image Texture node helped.